# CakePHP list finder method not returning array as expected

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cake's `$table->find('list')` finder method to retrieve an array of associated users [id => name]. Have used it in the past and its worked well. In this find I'm containing a belongsToMany table and retrieving [id => name].

In `\App\Model\Table\SitesTable::initialize` the ClientUsersWithAuthorities belongsToMany relationship is defined

```
$this->belongsToMany('ClientUsersWithAuthorities', [
  'className'        => 'AppUsers',
  'joinTable'        => 'sites_client_users',
  'foreignKey'       => 'site_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
  'propertyName'     => 'client_users_with_authorities']);
```

In `\App\Controller\ClientGroupsController::getClientgroupUsers`

```
$siteClientUsers = $this->Sites->find('list', [
  'keyField'   => 'client_users_with_authorities.id',
  'valueField' => 'client_users_with_authorities.full_name'])
->where(['id' => $siteId])
->contain(['ClientUsersWithAuthorities'])
->toArray();
```

$siteClientUsers returns `[0 => null]` instead of `[1234 => 'Client 1 name', 5678 => 'Client 2 name']` as expected. Both users exist in the join table.

Three other methods (below) return the array I'm looking for and which I'm expecting `$this->Sites->find('list')` to produce.
The cookbook describes associated data can be listed.
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

So why isn't `$this->Sites->find('list')` producing the expected array?

**mapReduce**

```
$mapper = function ($data, $key, $mapReduce) {
if (!empty($data['client_users_with_authorities'])) {
    foreach ($data['client_users_with_authorities'] as $user) {
        $mapReduce->emit($user);
    }}};
$siteClientUsers = $this->Sites->find('list', [
    'keyField'   => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'full_name'])
->where(['id' => $siteId])
->contain(['ClientUsersWithAuthorities'])
->mapReduce($mapper)
->toArray();
```

**Hash::combine**

```
$siteClientUsers = $this->Sites->find('all')
->where(['id' => $siteId])
->contain(['ClientUsersWithAuthorities'])
->toArray();
$siteClientUsers  = Hash::combine($siteClientUsers,'{n}.client_users_with_authorities.{n}.id', '{n}.client_users_with_authorities.{n}.full_name');
```

**Temp belongsTo** relationship on the join table

```
$table = $this->getTableLocator()->get('SitesClientUsers');
$table->belongsTo('Users', [
'className'   => 'AppUsers',
'foreign_key' => 'user_id']);
$siteClientUsers =  $table->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'Users.id',
    'valueField' => 'Users.full_name'
])
->select(['Users.id', 'Users.full_name'])
->where(['SitesClientUsers.site_id' => $siteId])
->contain(['Users'])
->toArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cookbook says:

> You can also create list data from associations that can be reached with joins

The important part being "*that can be reached with joins*", which isn't the case for `belongsToMany` associations. Given that list transformation happens on PHP level, the description should maybe focus on that instead, but it's still kinda valid as it stands.

`client_users_with_authorities` will be an array, ie possibly multiple records, so you cannot use it to populate a parent record - one `Sites` record represents one list entry. If you want to find a list of `ClientUsersWithAuthorities` that belongs to a specific site, then you can either use one of your other solutions (or something similar to that), or you could for example query from the other side of the association and use a matcher on `Sites`:

```
$query = $this->Sites->ClientUsersWithAuthorities
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'full_name'
    ])
    ->matching('Sites', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($siteId) {
        return $query->where([
            'Sites.id' => $siteId
        ]);
    })
    ->group('ClientUsersWithAuthorities.id');
```

This would create joins based on `Sites.id`, so that you'd only retrieve the `ClientUsersWithAuthorities` that are associated with `Sites` where `Sites.id` matches `$siteId`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

Comment: Top answer, thank you. I like the idea of approacing the list from the other side of the association in the first instance and using a matcher. In your opinion would using a 'hasMany through' association on Site allow find('list') to operate as I was expecting?

Comment: @chopstik Not really, unless you'd use it like the 3rd variant from your question, ie query via the join table. When using `contain()` the ORM will always retrieve `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` associations in a separate query, and leave you with the associated records set in an array on the respective parent record.